# testNG: sending report via mail within the @AfterSuite section

Tags: email, selenium, report, testng

I'd like to send the report generated by testNG ( java+eclipse+testNG) within the @AfterSuite section.
It's not a problem to send it, but the point is that the report is generated after the @AfterSuite section, so , basically, i send the previous one instead of the last one !
Any idea about how can I solve it ?

Answer (score 2):

As you are seeing, @AfterSuite runs before the report is generated.

Have you though about implementing a [TestNG IReporter listener](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#testng-listeners) ?

```
public class MyReporter implements IReporter {


        @Override
        public void generateReport(List<XmlSuite> xmlSuites, List<ISuite> iSuites, String s) {

            //Create your bespoke results

            //Email results
        }
    }
```

Obviously you can see a flaw in that you have to generate your own results from the raw results data (which may be advantageous if you just want to email a subset of data).

The ideal solution would to be able to extend the default report generator, but I am not sure this can be done.  However there is an existing listener provided by http://reportng.uncommons.org/, which actually provides a much nicer report output.

If you extend this this class, and call their code, and then add email generator code afterwards, it may work

```
public class MyReporter extends HTMLReporter {


        @Override
        public void generateReport(List<XmlSuite> xmlSuites, List<ISuite> iSuites, String s) {
            super.generateReport(xmlSuites, iSuites, s);

            //Email results
        }
    }
```

You can attach a listener to a test suite in several ways, as explained on the TEstNG website (http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#listeners-testng-xml)

An alternative to all of this woudl be to use a build tool like Maven to run your tests, then have a post test event to email the results.

Answer (score 0):

I copied the answer from [Krishnan](http://grokbase.com/t/gg/selenium-users/127ze9cnpk/how-to-automatically-email-emailable-report-html-after-every-test-run).
It works for me.
By the way, in my test environment, I need to extends the org.testng.reporters.EmailableReporter2 instead of EmailableReporter to make sure the correct count.
See below for your reference:

---

> > Krishnan Mahadevan Krishnan Mahadevan    at Jul 31, 2012 at 8:58 am       I am guessing that you are referring to the TestNG generated
> >     "emailable-report.html" which you would want to mail.
>
> With that assumption here's how you should be able to do it.
>
> 1. Extend org.testng.reporters.EmailableReporter
> 2. Override org.testng.reporters.EmailableReporter.generateReport(List,
>      List, String) and have it do something as below :
>
>    @Override
>      public void generateReport(List xml, List suites, String
>      outdir) {
>           super.generateReport(xml, suites, outdir);
>           SendFileEmail e= new SendFileEmail();
>           e.sendEmail();
>      }
>
> Now add up this listener of yours into your suite file using
>     tag.